# read environment vars in a simple react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I create an app with `create-react-app` module, and in a component, I'm trying to read an env. var, like this

```
<p style={textStyle}>Environment: { process.env.AWS_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV }</p>
```

I start the app with `AWS_ENV=live npm start` and it never reads this var. the result is always `development`. I noticed tho, if I build the app with `npm run build`, the output will be `production`, but anyway I cannot read the AWS_ENV var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**create-react-app** using https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv. To load ENV into Webpack and to pass it in browser, run this commands in console:

```
echo -e 'REACT_APP_AWS_ENV=live' > .env
npm start
```

Note `REACT_APP_` prefix special to **create-react-app**.

Then in your components:

```
...
{ process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ENV }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set `AWS_ENV` var in your webpack.prod.js.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
        'AWS_ENV': JSON.stringify('live npm start')
      }
    }),
```

Comment: Should be: `AWS_ENV: JSON.stringify('live')`

Comment: @LuizE. _create-react-app_ uses webpack internally. `process.env` is not available in a browser if it is not defined explicitly.